# Mark unmark javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a function to select all checkboxes in a table:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function checkAll() {
            var tab = document.getElementById("logs");
            var elems = tab.getElementsByTagName("input");
            var len = elems.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (elems[i].type == "checkbox") {
                    elems[i].checked = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

But I can't get it to uncheck them all if they are checked.  How could I do that?

```
<th width='2%'><a href="#" onclick="checkAll();">Mark</a></th>";
```

Also in javascript is it possible to rename "Mark" to "Un-Mark" if I execute `checkAll()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do both of the things u want:

```
function checkAll(obj) {
        var tab = document.getElementById("logs");
        var elems = tab.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var len = elems.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (elems[i].type == "checkbox") {
                if(elems[i].checked == true){
                    elems[i].checked = false;
                }
                else{
                    elems[i].checked = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if(obj.innerHTML == 'Mark') { obj.innerHTML = 'Unmark' }
        else { obj.innerHTML = 'Mark' }
    }
```

html:

```
<th width='2%'><a href="#" onclick="checkAll(this);">Mark</a></th>";
```

Comment: This is perfect neal:) It was exactly what I was wondering how to do, thank you for showing me how!

Comment: You could shorten this a lot by using `elems[i].checked = !elems[i].checked` or even `elems[i].checked ^= 1`.  This would allow you to get rid of the inner nested `if` statement.  Note also that this (and your solution) will merely toggle each checkbox individually, switching checked ones off and unchecked ones on regardless of whether you clicked to "Mark" all or "Unmark" all.

Comment: @Andy E , yes that is true, @Kelly s solution will toggle all

Answer (score 3):

1) why don't u use some js framework, like jQuery?

2) to remove checked, use elems[i].removeAttribute('checked') or set elems[i].checked = false;

3) to rename, you have to set it's innerHTML or innerText to Un-Mark

Comment: there is no reason to add jquery to something so small!

Comment: it wasn't a subject, i've just suggested

Answer (score 2):

Add a little more logic to see if they're already checked.  This will invert their current checked state.

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   if (elems[i].type == "checkbox") {
     if (!elems[i].checked) {
       elems[i].checked = true;
     }
     else elems[i].checked = false;
   }
}
```

If you just want to uncheck all, simply use:

```
elems[i].checked = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

This will **check them all** regardless of their current state, or uncheck them all, depending on the current text of "Mark" or "Unmark".

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkAll(obj) {
        var tab = document.getElementById("logs");
        var elems = tab.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var len = elems.length;
        var state = obj.innerHTML == 'Mark';
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (elems[i].type == "checkbox") {
                elems[i].checked = state;
            }
        }
        obj.innerHTML = state ? 'Mark' : 'Unmark';
    }
```

And then the HTML changes to:

```
<th width='2%'><a href="#" onclick="checkAll(this);">Mark</a></th>";
```

Comment: you type too fast! :) actually, mine doesn't just invert the current state, it does what the checkAll() function is supposed to do regardless of their current state.

Comment: lol wasnt sure exactly what the op wanted, the OP said `uncheck them all if they are checked` so it is a little vague

Comment: @Neal yeah apparently my answer was least useful :) i'll leave it around in case someone happens to need a `check all/uncheck all` route.

Comment: lol ok ^_^ ive emplemented it before in jquery. but that was when i was doing other things as well in jQuery and needed the library hehe

Comment: This gets my +1.  Not sure about anyone else but if I click a label named "Mark", I don't expect checkboxes I've already checked to be unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

To uncheck, try:

```
elems[i].checked = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

i sugest you use jquery, everything is easier.

with jquery you just have to do something like this (+/-):

```
$(function(){

    $('a.ClassName').click(function(){
      var oTbl = $('#tableID');
      $('input[type="checkbox"]', oTbl).attr("checked", "checked")
    });

})
```

Comment: well, the problem is that usually your website starts to need a lot of little trivial things, and when you lookback you have to consider that 29kb is less tahn some images that you're using on the site, right?